# python flask code - on windows through HTTP request

Tags: python, windows, web-services, http, flask

I have come with python flask code which uses  python libraries pywin32 and pYAD. I need to run these  in production enviornment.
I tried to enable it over IIS through wfastcgi but its not working as expected.

Is there a way I can leverage the script to use  in production set up, I have tried using Always Up converting script as a service but its not allowed in my organization similar with NSSM.

Is  there any other way to explore this. Kindly help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try waitress. You'll find the documentation [Here](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/).

> Install Waitress

```
pip install waitress
```

> setup.py file

```
from waitress import serve
import main
serve(main.app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080) #'main.app' being your entry point
```

run setup.py and access your app through `http://host_ip_address:8080`